# Translation for a "male Adult"

Tags: noun

Does the German translation for the noun "Adult" end in "e" or in "er"? Both endings are shown in various online dictionaries, such as dict.cc or leo.dict.org.

Comment: Be very careful - adulte/-er is usually used as adjective and not outside a scientific context. You might want to add more details to your question, e.g. with sample phrases. And all new users are encouraged to take the [tour] and browse our [help].

Comment: You could have named the German word. Most of the time, there is not just one translation for a word.

Comment: @Stephie The OP doesn't mean adulte/r, rather the German translation (which must be included, if the question is to remain open).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is unclear (the translation of *adult* should be included). And, by the way, could also end in *m* or *n*.

Comment: The entry in [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=adult) clearly shows why and it also gives the answer to the question (*m* stands for male).

Answer (score 3):

The ending depends on the gender and on the definiteness (if you use it definite or indefinite):

- indefinite

  > A female adult = Eine Erwachsene
  >   A male adult = Ein Erwachsener
- definite

  > The female adult = Die Erwachsene
  >   The male adult = Der Erwachsene

(And of course it also depends on the grammatical case: *»Ich sehe den Erwachsenen.«*)

This is because this word is a nominalized adjective, and although it is a noun it inherits some properties from its adjectival origin, and so its inflection also depends on [definiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness).

Comment: @Takkat: Ja, ich habe die Frage gelesen, verstanden und beantwortet. (Im Gegensatz zu jemand anderem, dessen falsche Antwort mich veranlasst hat, den Kommentar zu verfassen, den du hier zitierst.) Der Begriff *»Definitheit«* wurde in der Frage zwar nicht verwendet, aber sie ist genau der Grund dafür, warum es *»der Erwachsen**e**«* (ohne r) aber *»ein Erwachsen**er**«* (mit r) heißt. Und exakt danach hat der OP explizit gefragt. Implizit wurde daher sehr wohl nach der linguistischen Definitheit gefragt.

Comment: Tofros leider von ihm gelöschte Antwort auf diese aus gutem Grund geschlossene Frage ist weder richtiger noch falscher als Deine Antwort hier, aber Dein schnippisches Kommentar dort war ziemlich überflüssig.